# How to get single file from zip file?

Tags: vb.net, extract, unzip

I want to get just one file from `.zip` file in VB.NET. I don't need to extract all of `.zip` file, just one file.

I'm working with framework 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5 has `ZipFile` class which can do this for you. This code should get you started:

```
Dim zipPath As String = "Sample.zip"
Using archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read)
  Dim entry = archive.GetEntry("MyFile.pdf")
  Using reader As New BinaryReader(entry.Open())
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("MyFile.pdf", ReadAllBytes(reader))
  End Using
End Using
```

`ReadAllBytes()` is a helper method that fetches all bytes from a binary stream:

```
Public Shared Function ReadAllBytes(reader As BinaryReader) As Byte()
    Const bufferSize As Integer = 4096
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim buffer(bufferSize) As Byte
        Dim count As Integer
        Do
            count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            If count > 0 Then ms.Write(buffer, 0, count)
        Loop While count <> 0

        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

Make sure you're using .NET Framework 4.5 or above and that you have included references to `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code with the help of [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

```
Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile)
    Dim e As ZipEntry = zip("DocumentToFind.txt")
    e.Extract(OutputStream)
End Using
```

otherwise you can use [`ZipArchiveClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) in this way

```
Using zip As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipfile, ZipArchiveMode.Read)
Dim file = zip.Entries.Where(Function(x) x.Name = "fileToFind")
If file IsNot Nothing Then
    file.ExtractToFile("yourFile")

End If
```

End Using

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to read txt files from a zip line by line

```
Dim zipPath As String = "ZIP FILE LOCATION"
        Using zipStream = New FileStream(last_pafx23_open, FileMode.Open)
            Using archive = New ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read)
                For Each ent In archive.Entries
                    MsgBox(ent.ToString)
                    Using stream = ent.Open()
                        Using reader = New StreamReader(stream)
                            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                                MsgBox(reader.ReadLine)
                            End While
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the BinaryReader w/ ReadAllBytes() helper function, use ExtractToFile() instead:

```
Imports System.IO.Compression

Using archive = ZipFile.Open("Sample.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read)
  Dim entry = archive.GetEntry("MyFile.pdf")
  If entry IsNot Nothing then entry.ExtractToFile("MyFile.pdf")
End Using
```

Still needs the references to `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`, of course.

Comment: I can't comment on the top answer, my answer here is a simplified version.  I do commend the helper function in that answer though, for times when one desires to extract an item from the zip archive without having to write it to disk first.

Comment: Doesn't compile

Comment: Of course it won't compile!  The Imports would need to be above the class/module declaration.  It compiles just fine.  This code does exactly what the OP wanted and should be marked as the answer instead of having down votes!  The marked answer is reading the file in to memory and technically that isn't what was asked in the question.